# AWS support multiple Target Groups per ALB Listener

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli, amazon-elb, aws-elb

I'm trying to create a listener for my AWS ALB and attach my 2 target groups to that listener using the "create-listener" command (AWS CLI), but having issues creating the listener with those 2 target groups.

When creating the listener from the AWS Console and attaching both target groups it works as expected, or hen using the hardcoded arns of the target groups with the above syntax it works:

```
listener=$(aws elbv2 create-listener --load-balancer-arn $lb_arn --protocol HTTP --port $http_external_port --default-actions '[{"Type": "forward", "Order": 1, "ForwardConfig": {"TargetGroups": [{"TargetGroupArn": "HARDCODED_FIRST_TG_ARN", "Weight": 50}, {"TargetGroupArn": "HARDCODED_SECOND_TG_ARN", "Weight": 50}]}}]')
```

However, when using the ARNs as variables (which works) - the 'create-listener' command fails with the above error message:

```
first_tg_arn=$(aws elbv2 describe-target-groups --names $first_tg_name --query "TargetGroups[*][TargetGroupArn]" --output text)
second_tg_arn=$(aws elbv2 describe-target-groups --names $second_tg_name --query "TargetGroups[*][TargetGroupArn]" --output text)

listener=$(aws elbv2 create-listener --load-balancer-arn $lb_arn --protocol HTTP --port $http_external_port --default-actions '[{"Type": "forward", "Order": 1, "ForwardConfig": {"TargetGroups": [{"TargetGroupArn": "${first_tg_arn}", "Weight": 50}, {"TargetGroupArn": "${second_tg_arn}", "Weight": 50}]}}]')
```

> An error occurred (ValidationError) when calling the CreateListener
> operation: '${first_tg_arn}' is not a valid target group ARN

Above attached both ways running the command (with hardcoded ARNs and using the ARNs variables).
[image]

What could be the problem? Thank you.

Comment: Where are you running the command? Windows (PowerShell, cmd), Mac, Linux (which shell)?

Comment: It's a shell script running from Windows.

Comment: Within the JSON, you would need to put the ARNs within quote marks, and possibly the numbers too. Worst case, you can provide the JSON in a file. For an example, see: [aws-cli: awscli/examples/elbv2/create-rule.rst | Fossies](https://fossies.org/linux/aws-cli/awscli/examples/elbv2/create-rule.rst)

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is about Linux variable expansion, not exactly about AWS CLI usage.
On your command that is failing you are using single quote `'`, which will not expand variables to its value.
To expand variables you need to use double quote `"` or no quote at all, as you did in your second example.

Comment: Not worked, without quotes at all I'm getting the error: 
Error parsing parameter '--default-actions': Invalid JSON:
[{Type:

With double quotes, I'm getting the error:
Expecting property name enclosed in double quotes: line 1 column 3 (char 2)

Comment: Try double quotes outside and single quotes inside.

Answer (score 0):

The below command will work:

```
aws elbv2 create-listener --load-balancer-arn <alb arn> --protocol HTTPS --port 443 --certificates CertificateArn=value --default-actions 'Type=forward,ForwardConfig={TargetGroups=[{TargetGroupArn=value,Weight=1},{TargetGroupArn=value,Weight=1},{TargetGroupArn=value,Weight=1}]}'
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).